# Increasing sensor resolution by repeat measurement

Tags: repeated-measures, repeatability

I have a thermometer which has resolution of 1C. The temperature is measured, the thermometer is reset, and the temperature is measured again.

I'm looking for a formula to calculate how many experiments should I do to get the temperature with accuracy 0.1C with confidence 90%?

Comment: What is the variance of the measurement error, and what are the mean and variance of the underlying temperature? Are they normally distributed?

Comment: Lets' assume that the mean is 20C, and the variance is 2/3 (temperature randomly fluctuates within 1C of the mean). The distribution is normal

Comment: The thermometer only outputs $19$, $20$, or $21$, right? Is there measurement error associated with the thermometer's readings?

Comment: Let's assume that the only error we see is due to low resolution

Comment: I think this won't work. Let's make mean temperature 20.4, and error variance .1, and the measurement is going to fluctuate between 20 and 21